# Pyspark - Grouping on very large dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm grouping 200M records, and when I try aggregating on one of the groups (20M records in this group), it's throwing this error.

```
22/01/23 10:36:24 ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 584, in main
    eval_type = read_int(infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 564, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 2147483644, length: 11 (expected: range(0, 2147483648))
```

I don't think that the aggregate function is causing this since I tried supplying an empty function, and it still throws this error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like & it's clear from the message, somewhere in data, the length mismatch in data arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what do you mean? I actually tried casting all records in the column to string. e.g. each record looks like "[ ["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"]", but it's still throwing this same error

Comment: Here you can see `["a"]` is of length 1, `["b", "c"]` is of length 2. You should try to convert `["a"]` -> `["a", ""]`, something like this. I think, this idea/approach will work.